# Force an element style change to take effect immediately (in the current frame)

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, overflow, touchstart

I have an element whose `overflowY` equals `hidden`.

I'm capturing a `touchstart` event on the `window`:

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', handler, true);
```

In the `handler`, I want to make my element to be scrollable **before** the `touchstart` event reaches it.

```
element.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
```

Unfortunately this does not work, for one of two possible reasons:

- The element is already deemed "unscrollable" by the time `handler` is called.
- The changed `style.overflowY` will not take effect until the next frame.

Is there a way to get around this?

In my scenario, I **cannot** make the element scrollable before the `touchstart` event.

The reason my element has `overflowY: hidden` in the first place is to prevent any previous scroll animation while a custom animation is running.

Comment: What I understand is you want an action to be performed before the event occurs. Am I right?

Comment: @frederick99 The element needs to have `overflowY: scroll` in effect by the time `touchstart` bubbles up. This way, the element can be scrolled even though it had `overflowY: hidden` before the `touchstart` event occurred.

Comment: @frederick99 By capturing the `touchstart` event using `window.addEventListener`, I'm hoping to make the element immediately scrollable.